# How to create keyboard shortcut for displaying ruler in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext2, rulers

What I want is to **toggle** *Sublime Text 2* **rulers visibility** with a keyboard shortcut.

The only information I have got on topic is that rulers can be controlled by following JSON code in Preferences:

```
{
"rulers": [80, 120],
}
```

Is it possible to create such a keyboard shortcut?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can add this in your user key bindings settings (menu `Sublime Text 2/Preferences/Key Bindings - User`):

```
{ 
  "keys": ["YOUR_ENABLE_RULERS_SHORTCUT"],
  "command": "set_setting",
  "args":
  {
    "setting": "rulers",
    "value": [80, 120]
  }
}
```

To disable rulers:

```
{ 
  "keys": ["YOUR_DISABLE_RULERS_SHORTCUT"],
  "command": "set_setting",
  "args":
  {
    "setting": "rulers",
    "value": []
  }
}
```

If you really want a toggle, you can create a new plugin (`Tools/New Plugin...`), with a code similar to this:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class ToggleRulersCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit, **kwargs):
        rulers = kwargs["values"] if self.view.settings().get("rulers") == [] else []
        self.view.settings().set("rulers", rulers)
```

Save the plug-in in your `Packages/User` directory, with name `ToggleRulers.py`.

Then, add this key binding:

```
{ 
    "keys": ["YOUR_TOGGLE_RULERS_SHORTCUT"], "command": "toggle_rulers", 
    "args": { "values": [80, 120] } 
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU. The plugin answer was perfect. I mapped it to shift+option+r (no default conflict and easy to reach)